# A bug in encoding while storing html-based blog posts using php and jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, character-encoding

I am writing a code to post html-based blog posts through jquery/ajax to php to amazon s3.

I first urlencode the post with this function from php.js - http://phpjs.org/functions/urlencode:573 then send it to a php which stores the content as is to s3. If i read this file naked, it looks fine with slashed for special characters like " ' ", " " ", etc. which im able to remove with stripslashes.

Now, the problem, if I echo these s3 contents after retrieving with tarzan/CloudFusion library, it echos charactres like â€™, â€œ for " ' ", " " " respectively , but if i send this content through ajax/json encoding it looks all fine.

What exactly am I doing wrong? can someone also shed a light on encodings related in this case or in general.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `â€™` is typical for a [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded **curly** singlequote `’` being incorrectly decoded as [CP-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).
The `â€œ` is typical for a [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded **curly** doublequote `“` being incorrectly decoded as [CP-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).
*Those things are also called "smart" quotes, referring to the ones MS Word is by default using*.

So, somewhere in your layers you are using CP-1252 instead of UTF-8 to *display* those characters. Most likely you're using Windows and your PHP file is saved/served using CP-1252. Verify the response headers. At least, start adding the following line to the PHP file *before* any other template text content to force the webbrowser to display those characters using UTF-8:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

#### See also:

- [PHP UTF-8 cheatsheet](http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!

I tried setting the headers, but it didn't work :( , but i'll try looking for CP-1252 encoding to check whether its happening anywhere. But, I doubt s3 sends CP-1252.

Comment: hey...it actually worked. I wasn't checking it properly...sorry for that!

Thank you very much! You made my day :)